# Getting errors in IE 8 with apex/vf/JavaScript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, browser, internet-explorer

**Setup**

This is a VF page that is embedded in a STD layout. It's function is to conditionally render, display a warning, and do a redirect.

**Problem**

This code works fine in IE 9, FF, and chrome, but NOT IE 8. What am I doing wrong/what's going on? The user clicks the 'ok' btn and he doesn't go anywhere. I tried this in Compatibility and Non-Compatiblity mode. OR the user will get sent to the "URL No Longer Exists" page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  standardStylesheets="true" extensions="OpportunityController"  >
    <body style="background:#f3f3ec" > 
        <apex:form id="form">
            <script>    
                function onComplete2(){
                    var r=confirm("Click OK to continue and change the Record Type without saving changes. To save any changes, click cancel and then save your work");
                    if (r==true){
                       window.parent.parent.window.location = ("{!redirect}");
                    }         
                }    
            </script>
            <center>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" reRender="form" onComplete="onComplete2()" value="Change Record Type"/>
           </center>
    </apex:form>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

Apex

```
public with sharing class OpportunityController {

    String oppId;

    public OpportunityController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        getRender();               
    }

    public PageReference getredirect(){
        PageReference p;
        String s = '/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?id=' + this.oppId +'&retURL=%2F'+ this.oppId;
        p = new PageReference(s);
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;   
    }

    public boolean getRender(){
       if ( UserInfo.getProfileid().left(15) == '00e30000000bulF') {  //00e30000000bulF = sys admin.
           return true;
       }

      Group g = [select id from group where developerName = 'test'];
      List <GroupMember> gm = [Select UserOrGroupId, GroupId From GroupMember where groupId = :g.id];
      for(GroupMember x: gm){
          if (userinfo.getUserId().left(15) == x.UserOrGroupId){
              return true;
          }
     }
    return false;           
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess did you try window.location.href instead and see if the redirect works?

Comment: In IE in the bottom left corner check for yellow triangle with exclamation mark icon and check if there are any errors

Comment: @rao I tried that, and instead of the btn doing nothing, it now goes to a page "URL No Longer Exists" before it wouldn't do anything

Comment: Can you please view the source of the page in IE and paste the code that is on line 7?

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Timestamp: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 01:33:32 UTC


Message: Syntax error
Line: 25
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://c.cs15.visual.force.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=066e00000008wyu&ic=1

Comment: Try window.top.location.href = '{!redirect}';

Comment: (Unrelated to the question posed) This is dangerous code and is specific to the environment which this code resides in: `if ( UserInfo.getProfileid().left(15) == '00e30000000bulF')` it should be changed to either use a custom setting to store this value or use something like this to get the name of the profile dynamically. `String profileName = ([SELECT Profile.Name FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()]).Profile.Name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The code worked in Firefox and Chrome but didn't work on Internet Explorer 8. Here's what I have come up with!

Try replacing your

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" reRender="form" onComplete="onComplete2()" value="Change Record Type"/>
```

with

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" reRender="form" onComplete="return onComplete2();" value="Change Record Type"/>
```

Comment: Optionally, raise the quality bar for your users and demand they at least use ie9. I realize tats not always possible etc. but it's good to fight the good fight.